# SendMail using outlook credits Java

Tags: jakarta-mail

I am wondering how to send mail using outlook credits without entering additional details like host, port, username, pass in the java program. I used desktop.mail() but it opens the mailInterface which I doesnt want to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the libraries like

```
JWS,Jacob
```